# how to fetch tables from database of mysql in JtextArea with checkbox in swing

Tags: java, swing

Actually I want fetch tables and display like following image

[image: valid XHTML].

Can you help me?

Comment: And you want to interact with your table inside `JTextArea`?

Comment: ya i want to interact with tables inside in JTextArea

Answer (score 2):

Steps:

1. Run a query on your database to retrieve the tables and their meta data.
2. Store the results in suitable objects and pass them to your front end
3. Use `JXTreeTable` from SwingX but customize the Renderer and Editor for it to display and allow users to interact with the check boxes.

Realize this is a complex GUI component you are creating so don't try it all in one shot, get the JXTreeTable working with your data, then try to add in the check boxes.

Comment: ya i understand that you want to say...can you give a example or link

Comment: There is not a link or example to a single place that contains everything you need to create this.  You have several core pieces here you need to combine. (Database connections, running queries, pulling from a result set, the structure of an MVC app, using a JXTree Table, customizing renderers and editors, etc).